# How to fix 'incompatible type' for specified parameter in function call?

Tags: c, parameters

I have the following definitions/declarations in .h:

```
    typedef enum NODETYPE {
        HEAD = -1,
        BODY = 0,
        TAIL = 1
    } NodeType;

    /*  node sruct  */
    typedef struct NODE {
        enum NODETYPE type;
        int len;
        struct NODE * next;
    } Node;  
    
    /*  create node  */
    static Node CreateNode(NodeType type, int len, Node child) {
        Node n = (Node){type, len};
        n.next = &child;

        return n;
    }

    #define CREATE_NODE(type, len, node)                CreateNode((type), (len), (node))
```

Upon compile (using Code::Blocks), I get the following complaint:

> 285 | error: incompatible type for argument 3 of 'CreateNode'

Line 285, specifically, is the **`#define`** clause.

What do I have wrong?

I have the following that further extends the **`#define`** clause above:

```
    #define TLNODE()                                    CREATE_NODE(TAIL, -1, NULL)
    #define HDNODE()                                    CREATE_NODE(HEAD, -1, TLNODE())
```

In code I am calling as follows:

```
Node head = HDNODE();
```

**Update**
Took advice of several comments and the answer. Here are changes I've made and the problem is resolved.

```
static Node* CreateNode(NodeType type, int len, struct NODE* child) {
    struct NODE* n = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));

    n->type = type;
    n->len = len;
    n->next = child;

    return n;
}

#define CREATE_NODE(type, len, node)                (Node*)CreateNode((type), (len), (node))
#define TLNODE()                                    (Node*)CREATE_NODE(TAIL, -1, NULL)
#define HDNODE()                                    (Node*)CREATE_NODE(HEAD, -1, TLNODE())
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: You probably want to pass a pointer to a Node or a pointer to a pointer to a node depending upon whether or not that argument is a return value. Then you won't have to take the address of the child. There's not enough context to know for sure. Show the caller of this function and the definition of the arguments passed by the caller. One of the callers, TLNODE, uses NULL. That's a pointer to a Node. The other calls TLNODE. So, it needs to be a pointer in the signature.

Comment: `n.next = &child;` stores a pointer to a local copy that's left dangling when the function completes.

Comment: Show the call to `CreateNode`.  Even if you were calling it correctly, it has a severe bug, which is that it's saving a pointer to the `child` argument , which is a local variable.  That object will no longer be valid after the function returns.  You probably intended for the `child` argument to be a pointer, but you didn't declare it as such.  It would also make sense for it to return a pointer to a dynamically allocated node rather than copying the whole structure and leaving it to the caller to allocate storage for it.

Comment: added the enum defined in node struct. does that give enough for **minimal reproducible example**?

Comment: You need to show the call to CreateNode.  Preferably with the macros expanded.

Comment: @TomKarzes: I don't know what you mean *show the call to CreateNode*. It's in the macro. I call the macro from the code listed at the bottom of the question.

Comment: You code doesn't show TAIL or HEAD. It's impossible for us to see exactly what's getting passed to the function.

Comment: @jwdonahue: see the enum definition at the top of the question. `TAIL`, `HEAD`, `BODY`

Comment: Okay, I see it now. You are passing a NULL pointer to a function that requires a value parameter. And that's not the only thing that wrong with your code.

Comment: See @TomKarzes comment.

Comment: Ok, you're passing `NULL`, which is a pointer type (it has type `void *`), as the `Node` argument to `CreateNode`.  It probably *should* take a pointer, in which case that would be correct.  But that's causing the type mistmatch error.  You'd get a similar error if you tried to assign `((void *) 0)` to a variable with type `Node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TLNODE` is the faulty macro, but your code's design is a much bigger problem.

`TLNODE` cannot pass `NULL` to the 3rd argument of `CreateNode`, because `NULL` is usually defined as `((void*)0)` and represents a pointer, while `Node`'s type is defined by a structure.

Copying the pointer's address to a variable of type `struct` is illegal in C. You need to use the same `Node` type for the third parameter.

You could end up doing something like:

```
static const Node EMPTY_NODE = {};
```

And redefine your `TL_NODE` to use it:

```
#define TLNODE() CREATE_NODE(TAIL, -1, EMPTY_NODE)
```

This will probably help compiling the code, but the design still remains defective. The list you are creating is using the `CreateNode`'s stack frame, therefore the `Node:next` pointer will store a location on the stack that will soon be reused by another function. If you use that list, you will corrupt your own call stack.

You need to change `CreateNode`'s design to use pointers to `Node` and also allocate the Nodes dynamically (using `malloc`).

If you really want to use the stack for that, allocate a big buffer in your `main` (e.g.: `char _storage[2048]`) and create an allocator for nodes you want to create, within that 2KB space. Don't reference the call stack directly.

Comment: Your answer gave me a lot of insight to correcting `CreateNode` implementation. See update in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. Now it looks good. You can maybe drop the cast to `(Node*)` in the macros, to avoid confusion when someone reads the code. The first thing that may come to mind is that you are converting from a different pointer type.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether or not that was necessary. I'll remove it for clarity. Thanks.